# Scala: Using Option for key/value pairs in a list

Tags: list, scala, key, scala-option

I'm trying to write the get method for a key, value pair implemented using a list. I want to use the Option type as I heard its good for this but I'm new to Scala and I'm not really sure how to use it in this case...

This is as far as I got, only the method header.

```
def get(key : String): Option[Any] = {}
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are looking for something like this:

```
class KeyValueStore(pairs: List[(String, Any)]) {

  def get(key: String): Option[Any] = pairs.collectFirst {
    case (k, v) if k == key => v
  }

}
```

This uses the `collectFirst` method for sequences. If you want a more "do it yourself" approach, this should work:

```
def get(key: String): Option[Any] = {
  def search(xs: List[(String, Any)]): Option[Any] = {
    xs match {
      case List() => None //end of list and key not found. We return None
      case (k, v) :: rest if k == key => Some(v) // found our key. Returning some value
      case _ :: rest => search(rest) // not found until nou. Carrying on with the rest of the list
    }

    search(pairs)
  }
}
```

Comment: When doing that I get a type mismatch error. It returns a List but needs an Option.

Comment: Sorry. It's `collectFirst`, not `collect`. I fixed my answer

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. One more thing, any tips for remove? I'm trying to use the same principles as get but I'm having trouble keeping the elements that don't equal key in the list. Example: If my list is ("A",1),("B",2"),("C",3),("D",4) and I wanted to remove C, how would I ensure A, B, D are still there?

Comment: @aepurniet's suggestion would work. Also, filterNot may be more intuitive: `pairs filterNot { _ == key }`

Comment: I would have used `find`: `pairs.find(_._1 == k).map(_._2)`. I wonder if `collectFirst` is faster here?

Comment: I'm having a hard time using filter and filterNot. When I execute it, it doesn't seem to do anything to the list. Is there any other way? I'm trying to use Option on this as well.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that you're expecting the `filter` method to modify the list. Lists in Scala are immutable, they can't be changed. What filter does is to create a new list that contains only the elements that meet the criteria. That's idiomatic Scala - we don't change things - we create new ones. It may seem strange at first, but it works really well in practice. I've prepared some examples about how to implement your class. One includes a remove method that actually removes the element from the collection.The second one takes the recommended, immutable way http://pastebin.com/w0TTwZZD

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a List of Pairs into a Map:

```
class Store[K, V](values: List[(K, V)]) {
  val map = values.toMap
  def get(key: K): Option[V] = map get key
}
```

Comment: It's a bit cheating, isn't it? ;)

Comment: :) I wasn't sure if the question really wanted an answer working on the List or just getting a result directly.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Marius' `collectFirst` version is probably the most elegant (and maybe a little bit faster as it only uses one closure), I find it more intuitive to use `find` for your problem :

```
def get[A, B](key: A, pairs: List[(A, B)]): Option[B] = pairs.find(_._1 == key).map(_._2)
```

In case you were wondering (or need high performance), you will need either @Marius' recursive or the following imperative version which may look more familiar (although less idiomatic):

```
def get[A, B](key: A, pairs: List[(A, B)]): Option[B] = {
  var l = pairs
  var found: Option[B] = None
  while (l.nonEmpty && found.isEmpty) {
    val (k, v) = l.head
    if (k == key) {
      found = Some(v)
    } else {
      l = l.tail
    }
  }
  found
}
```

What you must understand is that `Option[B]` is a class that may either be instantiated to `None` (which replaces and improves the `null` reference used in other languages) or `Some(value: B)`. `Some` is a *case class*, which allows, among other neat features, to instantiate it without the `new` keyword (thanks to some compiler magic, Google *Scala case class* for more info). You can think of `Option` as a `List` which may contain either 0 or 1 element: most operations that can be done on sequences can also be applied to `Option`s (such as `map` in the `find` version).